# Using NLREG from C# without COM?

Tags: c#, .net, statistics

Is there a way to leverage NLREG in C#, or from any other .NET language?  Currently, we only can find it as a COM object, which gives us issues when we change platforms (32 to 64 and the like).

Comment: Looks to me like the guy fell asleep at least 10 years ago.  Doesn't even advertize a .NET version, his web site is definitely previous century look-and-feel.  Zero odds for 64-bit support, this code is native.  If you can't poke him awake with an email message, low odds, then move on.

Comment: Why the close vote? Seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually need the 64-bit memory space in your NLREG client, just set the target platform in your client project to x86 (not AnyCPU), then it'll always work regardless of 32- or 64-bit OS.

Your question wasn't clear if you were changing the target *compiled* platform for your client, or if you're trying to run on a 64-bit OS- I'm assuming the latter.